# Daisy Chaining USB Communication over Arduino Due

Tags: arduino-due, usb

I have two Arduino Due boards. I would like to connect one to my computer through the programming port as USB Serial so that I can send it commands, but I would like it to also be able to communicate to a second Arduino Due as the host on the native USB port.

I see in the manual that it has drivers for acting as a host to USB Mice and Keyboards, but is having it load appropriate drivers for communicating with another Due doable? I've done plenty with the USB ports, but never as a host so I'm not really sure how to start.

The goal is to have one "master" Due connected to the computer that controls a complicated piece of equipment with a lot of supporting electronics, and a second "peripheral" Due that acts as an interface for the user. The master would accept commands either from the computer, or from the peripheral. Reason is that the peripheral has to have fast interrupts to handle rotary encoders and the like (the "master" Due is quite busy so those interrupts can be troublesome) and be physically located in a different place.

Comment: Have you considered exposing one of the USARTs over USB, and connecting it to the other Due?

Comment: Using Serial (UART) or SPI would be a lot easier, and less burdensome on both the Arduinos